Is there a simple way to add a euclidean distance column to an existing PySpark dataframe?
I am surprised that I'm unable to find a simple way to use an outside array and the array from a pyspark column to create a new column based on euclidean distance.
Say I have the following dataframe and vector:
rdd = sc.parallelize([(0,[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]), (1,[0.2, 0.3, 0.1]), (2,[0.1, 0.3, 0.2])])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["id", "values"])

vector = [0.3, 0.2, 0.1]

I'd like to simply calculate the euclidean distance between the vector given and the values found in each row and then make this a new column. I'm fairly new to pyspark but haven't been able to find a way to do this. Here's where my intuition led me:

# define udf to calculate euclidean distance
def euclidean_distance(values, query_vector):
    return sqrt(sum((v - q) ** 2 for v, q in zip(values, query_vector)))

udf_euclidean_distance = F.udf(euclidean_distance)

# pass column through udf
df = df.withColumn('similarity_score', 
                                       udf_euclidean_distance(col('values'), lit(vector)))

However, I end up with the error

feature not supported.


Welcome to SO! Which Spark version do you use? Starting from version 3.4.0 lit supports list types. For earlier versions you should use an array of lit expressions instead of an lit expression of an array. Please check this answer

avoid using 'udf' for this kind simple expressions. UDF significantly reduces pySpark performance. Instead use native spark functions:
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


sc = SparkContext('local', 'test')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

rdd = sc.parallelize([(0,[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]), (1,[0.2, 0.3, 0.1]), (2,[0.1, 0.3, 0.2])])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["id", "values"])

vector = [0.3, 0.2, 0.1]


# Defining Spark function for cacluating MSE
# initializing MSE with zero value
func_mse = 0 

for i in range(len(vector)):
    # calculating squared difference for each coordinate dimension
    # (vect1.x1 - vect2.x1)**2 
    func_mse += f.pow(df['values'][i]-vector[i],2)

# finally taking a squared root
# RMSE = sqrt(MSE)
func_rmse = f.pow(func_mse, 0.5)

# creating new column in spark which will 
df = df.withColumn('rmse', func_rmse)

# check output
print(df.head(3))

also you can make Spark distance expression customizable by wrapping everything in the function:
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame as SparkDataFrame
from typing import List

def vector_rmse(df: SparkDataFrame, vector: List[int]):
    func_mse = 0
    for i in range(len(vector)):
        
        func_mse += f.pow(df['values'][i]-vector[i],2)

    func_rmse = f.pow(func_mse, 0.5)
    return func_rmse

df = df.withColumn('rmse2', vector_rmse(df, vector))

